# FileZip compression with cancellation

Tags: c#, compression, zip, cancellation, c#-ziparchive

How to cancel long running compression task and release all resources when using ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory or other ZipFile compression methods in C#.

Couldn't find any native method or parameter that help to cancel the compression.

Comment: You'd likely need to launch it in a separate thread, so that you have the option to kill the thread.

Comment: If you talking about cancellation token, it can only be used with custom cancel call, but when ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory method has been called you have to wait for it to act on cancellation state of token. And at that point compression has taken all the time that you want to avoid by stopping/cancelling the compression call.

Comment: No, I'm talking about aborting the thread.